# WordPress: max number of pages in Pagination is wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have 1379 posts published in a WordPress blog.
For some weird reason, I just noticed that pagination only works until page 154 (which is around 2006, whilst the first post was [published in 1999](https://bombacarta.com/1999/))..

`https://bombacarta.com/page/154/` works (last page)

`https://bombacarta.com/page/155/` doesn't (but it should..)

Archives by date do work (even for posts older than 2006).
Do you have any idea of what's causing this?

This is the function I'm using in `index.php` to get the posts:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'category'          => -7,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 8,
    'paged'             => $paged,
);

$articoli = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($articoli as $post) : setup_postdata($post); if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;

echo '<article>...</article>';

endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
```

I need that `$do_not_duplicate` because I have a featured post I'm showing just in the first page (home page).

EDIT: In the home page I also have 2 other loops that pull a specific page by ID and the featured post. Find the pastebin with the 3 functions **[here](http://pastebin.com/MbFKm8cd)**.

EDIT 2: There are just a few posts in cat 7 (excluded from the loop) - there are posts < 2006 from other categories as well. So it doesn't make a difference to have that category excluded.

Comment: Why do you create your own loop/query instead of using WP's default?

Comment: @powerbuoy I thought I couldn't have more than 1 default loop in the same page.. I have 3 different (custom) loops in the page. 1st is the featured post (the last post from a specific category), then the calendar (a specific page retrieved by page ID) and last the loop, the excludes the featured post (and has a few args). The 3 functions: http://pastebin.com/gF22sAW1

Comment: I get the other two loops because they're specific about something (a specific category or whatever), but this loop you're displaying here SHOULD just be the default `while (have_posts())` stuff. You're doing your own `get_posts` instead which seems wrong.

Comment: @powerbuoy I'll try changing it to the default loop, but it should work anyway.. no? Why would a custom loop display the wrong number of total pages? I'll post an update when I'm done changing the function

Comment: Are you sure that posts that you cant see have got same category as posts that you can see?

Comment: @TomaszWinter Yes I am sure.

Comment: @powerbuoy actually my code is just like the example given on wordpress.org.. so it must be correct. https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts It's something else..

Comment: @powerbuoy besides, I tried with if have posts while.. same thing.. still 154 pages.. nothing before 2006 (even if posts are published, not in the excluded category, etc)

Comment: Ok that's odd. Perhaps WP has some sort of limit? I'd still recommend using "the loop" for queries that are dependent on the route/URL as WP handles them automatically, and only use get_posts when you need to do something non standard.

Comment: I've done some further investigation.. So, my loop had posts_per_page set to 8, while my setting in Settings-Reading was set to 9 posts per page (by default). I changed that to 8 (to reflect my loop) and the last page for pagination jumped to 173. The issue now was that pages 173 and 172 were blank. I then tried commenting out the line that was excluding category 7 from the loop, and bang all 173 pages were populated. Now, what does this mean? The pagination seems to be somewhat broken.. it should adapt to the args in the loop, shouldn't it ?

Comment: It should adapt automatically to the number of posts in the loop (in this case reducing the total num. of pages to 171 because there were 12 posts in category excluded in the loop)...